# Font change, could not find why

Tags: firefox, menu, firebug

the site : http://academie-igs.com/?lang=fr. Look at the menu (french first menu) it's called : "environment de travail". when hover on, the word wrap and go to another line...

I use firebug to check the style sheet, take screen capture that i check in Photoshop. I cannot see the problem... why it append?

I don't know what do that behavior. Can you point me where to look ?...  it's a mystery for me right now !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with spacing.

Line 104 on superfish.css, replace with the following:

`.sf-menu li li a:hover {padding:8px 5px 8px 17px; background:#353535; background:-moz-linear-gradient(center top , #4C4C4C, #313131) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; color:#fff !important;  outline:0;  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#4C4C4C), to(#313131));}`

You had too much spacing on the right of it on hover on the `padding` property that was causing the text to wrap downward.